# How to Identify Redis performance/Bottlenecks

Tags: performance, redis, redis-cli

I wan to know that how to check the performance of Redis server and  what could be bottleneck. I have run redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 --stat command and get following stats.

[image]

if some can suggest what needs to be done and what other mtrics need to be checked.

Answer (score 3):

Redis includes the redis-benchmark utility that simulates running commands done by N clients at the same time

```
Usage: redis-benchmark [-h <host>] [-p <port>] [-c <clients>] [-n <requests]> [-k <boolean>]
```

MONITOR is a debugging command that streams back every command processed by the Redis server. It can help in understanding what is happening to the database. This command can both be used via redis-cli and via telnet.

```
$ redis-cli monitor
```

If you are experiencing latency problems, probably you know how to measure it in the context of your application, or maybe your latency problem is very evident even macroscopically. However redis-cli can be used to measure the latency of a Redis server in milliseconds, just try:

```
redis-cli --latency -h `host` -p `port`
```

Hope you can get some help from here.
Reference Link: http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Comment: There could be lot of way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this redis](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) topic about benchmark?

> The redis-benchmark program is a quick and useful way to get some figures and evaluate the performance of a Redis instance on a given hardware. However, by default, it does not represent the maximum throughput a Redis instance can sustain.

Comment: I did, can you explain the screenshot i have attached.

Comment: did you mean the meaning of every column?

Comment: I mean the number of connection and requests are the concurrent?

Comment: requests are commands sent to redis by connection. connections are number of successful connections (I've persistent connection, so requests are bigger than connections)

Answer (score 0):

To identify performance bottlenecks, invoke `slowlog get` in Redis-cli.
It will return the list of commands whose execution time exceeded a duration defined in redis.conf. This duration concerns only the processing of the requests, it does not include the communication time. The default value is one second, which is a lot for Redis.

Redis.conf includes two values related to slow logs:

- `slowlog-log-slower-than` defines the minimum execution time, inn microseconds, of the request to be logged;
- `slowlog-max-len` defines the maxum number of entries to be stored in the slow log.

As usual with Redis, you can use `config set` to modify these setting without restarting the server. just don't forget these logs are stored in memory.

You can clear the slow log entries using `slowlog reset`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also user [Redis Stat](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat), great tool for realtime checking.

Regards,